# Using python to query a field in a layer in ArcMap 10.6

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to query a field in a layer but it fails converting the nvarchar value '65N' to data type int. Is there a way I can prevent it from converting and simply just run a query and print the results?

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
RuntimeError: Underlying DBMS error [[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '65N' to data type int.] [NEO_1.SDE.P_Meters]
```

Python Code

```
import arcpy

fc = 'Database Connections\SDE.sde\NEO_1.SDE.P_PipeSystem\NEO_1.SDE.P_Meters'
field = 'SYSTEMNUMBER'


#systemList = ["9", "10", "12", "13", "21", "22", "27", "27A", "27B", "27C", "30", "31", "33", "34", "35", "36"]

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field, "SYSTEMNUMBER"), """"SYSTEMNUMBER" = 009""")
# For each row print the 
for row in cursor:
    # Print the name of the gas systems
    #
    print(row[1])
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
    print('{} has {} records'.format(row, result[0]))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Count the number of features with systemnumber 009? What is systemlist?

Comment: @BERA systemList is a dictionary of the systems I would like to impliment into the script when I am able to figure out how to successfully run '''"SYSTEMNUMBER" = 009'''. When I originally wrote the script I didn't realize Cursor was converting everything to an int

Comment: It is a list, not a dictionary. I still dont understand what you want to do

Comment: @BERA I would like the query to display the total number of meters in each system number.

Comment: Have you tried writing the sql clause like `expression = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, field) + ' = 9'`?

Comment: Select by attributes - summary statistics

Answer (score 2):

To count occurences use Collections.Counter:

```
import arcpy
from collections import Counter

fc = r"C:\database.gdb\features"
field = 'SYSTEMNUMBER'

d = Counter([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field)])
```

`d` is now a dictionary of systemnumbers and their count, for example:

```
>>>d
Counter({'100': 327596, '210': 39788, '200': 32381,...
>>>d['100']
327596
```

You can iterate using your list like this:

```
for n in ['100','501','211']:
    print '{0} has count: {1}'.format(number, d[n])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert it from a number to a string. Otherwise 009 becomes simply 9 and you are comparing a string to a int.

```
"""SYSTEMNUMBER = '009'"""
```

Code

```
import arcpy

fc = 'Database Connections\SDE.sde\NEO_1.SDE.P_PipeSystem\NEO_1.SDE.P_Meters'
field = 'SYSTEMNUMBER'

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field, "SYSTEMNUMBER"), """SYSTEMNUMBER = 
'009'""")
count = 0 

# For each row print the 
for row in cursor:
    # Print the name of the gas systems
    #
    #print(row[1])
    #result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
    #print('{} has {} records'.format(row[1], result[0]))
    count += 1  

print('{} has {} records'.format(row[1],count))
```